List of playlists not displaying Django music app
I'm making a music streaming website and I'm trying to display the users list of playlists in the <div id="divId">, but I always get that the user has no playlists (but there are playlists in database for the user). What is the problem? Maybe the playlist view is not correct?
html:
<div id="divId">
    {% if myPlaylists %}
        <p style="margin: 5px; font-size: 0.75rem; font-weight: 700; color: rgb(138, 138, 138); text-align: left;">Add This Song To Your Playlist</p>
    {% for playlist in myPlaylists %}
        <a class="left-panel-btn" id="D_{{playlist.playlist_id}}" onclick="sendPostRequestPlaylistSong(this)">{{playlistInfo.playlist_name}}</a><br>
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <p style="margin: 5px; font-size: 0.8rem; font-weight: 700; color: rgb(138, 138, 138); text-align: left;">You don't have any Playlist.</p>
        <a class="create-p" onclick="$('#divId').css({display: 'none'}); document.getElementById('modal-wrapper-playlist').style.display='block'"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Create Playlist</a>
    {% endif %}
</div>

models.py:
class Song(models.Model):
    song_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    album = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default='Album')
    song = models.FileField(upload_to="songs/", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['mp3', 'wav'])], default="name")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="songimage/", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'])], default="https://placehold.co/300x300/png")
    data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

class Playlist(models.Model):
    playlist_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    playlist_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="name")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="playlist_images/", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'])], default="media/images/music-placeholder.png")
    plays = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song, related_name='playlist')
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.playlist_name

views.py:
def playlist(request, playlist_id):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        myPlaylists = Playlist.objects.filter(user=user)
        if request.method == "POST":
            song_id = request.POST["music_id"]
            playlist = Playlist.objects.filter(playlist_id=playlist_id).first()
            if song_id in playlist.songs.all():
                playlist.songs.remove(song_id)
                playlist.plays -= 1
                playlist.save()
            message = "Successfull"
            print(message)
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message': message}))
        else:
            images = os.listdir("media/playlist_images")
            print(images)
            currPlaylist = Playlist.objects.filter(playlist_id=playlist_id).first()
            songs = currPlaylist.songs
            playlistSongs = [currPlaylist.songs.all()]
            recommendedSingers = []

            return render(request, "music/playlist.html", {'playlistInfo': currPlaylist,
                                                       'playlistSongs': playlistSongs,
                                                       'myPlaylists': myPlaylists,
                                                       'recommendedSingers': recommendedSingers})


Without debug it is hard to answer.
please provide the print result of those code for user with existed playlists:
# in your playlist view
myPlaylists = Playlist.objects.filter(user=user)
# put those two lines
print(myPlaylists.query.__str__())
print(myPlaylists.count())

By the way - you have an error in template:
{% for playlist in myPlaylists %}
    <a class="left-panel-btn" id="D_{{playlist.playlist_id}}" onclick="sendPostRequestPlaylistSong(this)">
        {{playlistInfo.playlist_name}} {# it should be playlist.playlist_name #}
     </a><br>
{% endfor %}


i got this in terminal:
SELECT "music_playlist"."playlist_id", "music_playlist"."user_id", "music_playlist"."playlist_name", "music_playlist"."image", "music_playlist"."plays", "music_playlist"."slug" FROM "music_playlist" WHERE "music_playlist"."user_id" = 1
2

and in template {{ myPlaylists.count }} before {% if myPlaylists %} also print 2, right?

i've made a p tag with {{ myPlaylists.count }} inside and it doesn't print anything...

it means, you don't have in template context "myPlaylists" variable. Can you add any dumb variable and check if it goes to template?

not working... i think that is because i had to add myPlaylist to the homepage view, where i'm trying to see the list. how can i do it?

are you use some extends/include in template? because you dont provide whole template code. In some cases with include context can be changed.

do you mean the imports?

i mean {% extends %} or {% include %} https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std-templatetag-extends

no, i'm not using extends and include

I added to the homepage.view the list of playlist like this:
def homepage(request):
songs = Song.objects.all()
user = request.user
if user.is_authenticated:
    my_playlists = Playlist.objects.filter(user=user)
return render(request, 'homepage.html', {'songs': songs, 'my_playlists': my_playlists})


and it works or not?

@MaximDanilov yes, now is working
